# Why doesn't this Regex match the date part of the input?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am attempting to take an Object's text value, obtain information from it through a Regex, and then type that output to Notepad. Below is my code, and the object references are all correct. I have been able to type other information to Notepad, including the full text of the object whose Regex I am trying to extract, so I assume there is a problem with the Match.Groups[1].Value, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
string pattern= @".*[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\s(A|P)M$";
string input = repo.ChangedByDate.Element.GetAttributeValueText("Text");

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

string dateRegex = match.Groups[1].Value;

Notepad.Textbox.PressKeys(dateRegex);
```

**EDIT:**
Apologies, I posted too quickly and without more pertinent information.

The above code is meant to match only the date/time portion of a string whose original text is:

```
Current date and time is: 8/7/2013 12:15:02 PM
```

So all I want to extract is `8/7/2013 12:15:02 PM` with the regex assigned to `pattern`.

As of now, no output is being placed into Notepad. However, if I were to change the code to just the following:

```
string input = repo.ChangedByDate.Element.GetAttributeValueText("Text");

Notepad.Textbox.PressKeys(input);
```

My output in Notepad is `Current date and time is: 8/7/2013 12:15:02 PM`

Comment: We're not mind readers. Tell us what `match.Groups[1].Value` contains. And `input` for that matter.

Comment: How is failure manifesting for you?  What's your question?

Comment: What is the exact problem or question here? Look at values in your debugger. Are they valid? We can't possibly debug this for you, especially not having any input/output.

Comment: You should check your match before you try accessing your groups. If the match isn't made what is the guarantee that you have anything assigned to your groups? if (match.Success)

Comment: As others have said, this question is unanswerable without input and output. But, most notably, we also need your _expected_ output. If we don't know what you want, how are we supposed to help you get it? What is it you actually want to see printed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` in your regex will match the start of the string. You can just exclude it entirely, and get group 0 (all the content matched by the regex). Note that you should also be checking for success before accessing groups.

```
string pattern= @"[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\s[AP]M";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
  string dateRegex = match.Groups[0].Value;
  Notepad.Textbox.PressKeys(dateRegex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

`Groups[0]` contains the entire match (likely the entire string given your RegEx).

`Groups[1]` contains the first grouping (in this case the "A" or "P", since you used `()`)

If this doesn't line up with what you are seeing you are going to have to give more detail as we do not have the input string and more importantly cannot look at the status of the `Match` object you are generating.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it for you:

```
.*([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\s[AP]M)$
```

First, you needed to group the entire Regex because you want the entire result, so that will now be in `Groups[1]`. Secondly, you just needed this, `[AP]M`, at the end of the Regex.

Here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/rO7OUQOdre).